# How did a single, non-diamond user delete someone else's question?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

[Encrypting an audio file using AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116937/encrypting-an-audio-file-using-aes) [10k] claims to have been deleted by **user2301355**. What happened here?

Comment: An Ex moderator?

Comment: @HugoDozois Do we have any of those on SO? I didn't think we did.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I thought there was 1 case on SO, but I might be wrong. I've seen discussions on the meta about a diamond quitting (or ragequitting, don't remember).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: A user named Dori used to be a moderator. Then you have [Sam Saffron](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron) (aka waffles) who used to be a dev.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII There are a few ex-moderators on SO. None of them were ragequits though.  They all stepped down due to availability and other responsibilities.

Comment: @animuson while you're at it, it's easy to see mods who aren't mods any longer in the [elections page](http://stackoverflow.com/election) right now there are two: SLaks and Lasse. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible that user2301355 was another account of the user who posted the question, and they were later merged, which causes this kind of discrepancy.

Comment: @animuson are you saying that you don't know everything about this site? :O

Comment: Those accounts were merged about 3 hours ago. It looks like the "deleted by" message doesn't get updated during the account merge script.  (Or maybe it does and it just leaves behind the old account id instead of the new account name?)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Shhhh, it's Tim and I's secret. o.o

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: It is never updated.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when a diamond mod deletes a question and later relinquishes the diamond.

Comment: It would still show the ex-moderator's real name, no?

Comment: There would have to be one more step here: account deletion and anonymization.

Comment: Has anyone lost the diamond in the last 8 hours?  :-)

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't explain this case, but a more general case